# The tool was unable to install Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime

Tags: installation, prerequisites

I've installed a fresh copy of Windows Server 2008 R2 into a virtual machine, using VirtualBox.

Now I'm trying to install the prerequisites for Sharepoint, using the "Microsoft Sharepoint Products and Technologies 2010 Preparation Tool".

Every time I run this tool, after some processing, I keep getting the following error:

> **The tool was unable to install Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime**
>
> - Application Server Role, Web Server (IIS) Role: configured successfully
> - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Native Client: installed successfully
> - Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime: installation error
> - Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x64): Installation skipped
> - Microsoft Chart Controls for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5: Installation skipped
> - Microsoft Filter Pack 2.0: Installation skipped
> - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services ADOMD.NET: Installation skipped

I've tried Googling the error but found only one link, which didn't resolve my issue.

I located the log file (using: 'cd %temp%' then 'dir /od *.log'), and noticed that it contains the following text:

```
2011-07-11 01:53:43 - Beginning download of Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime
2011-07-11 01:53:43 - http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/D/F3D66A7E-C974-4A60-B7A5-382A61EB7BC6/MicrosoftGenevaFramework.amd64.msi
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Download of "Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime" completed successfully
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Installing Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - "C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe" /i "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IDF850F.tmp.msi" /quiet /norestart
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Install process returned (0X654=1620)
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - [In HRESULT format] (0X80070654=-2147023276)
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Last return code (0X654=1620)
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Error: The tool was unable to install Microsoft "Geneva" Framework Runtime.
2011-07-11 01:53:44 - Last return code (0X654=1620)
```

Then I went to run the file "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\IDF850F.tmp.msi"  manually, and got a dialog saying:

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

Then I noticed that when I put the Geneva download URL into my browser, I just get a 404.

So I guess Microsoft have taken the file off their servers.

Is there any way I can fix this, or get Geneva from somewhere else, or install Sharepoint 2010 without installing Geneva? And isn't anyone else having the same issue?

Comment: are you speaking about this link : http://blogs.technet.com/b/paulpaa/archive/2009/11/28/error-while-installing-sharepoint-2010-preparation-tool-the-tool-was-unable-to-install-microsoft-geneva-framework-runtime.aspx? I can tell you also that url you can see in the log file to download Geneva is dead!

Comment: Yup you're right, it's dead. So how are people installing Sharepoint? Is there anywhere else I can get the file? I've been Googling for it, but haven't found any download links for about 20 pages.

Comment: OK, I found a download link here: http://connect.microsoft.com/site642/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=14696. I'm going to try running it and see what happens.

Comment: Nope, no luck. Ran the installer to the end and it said it was successful. But when I ran the prerequisites installer again, I just got the same old message, and the log is also exactly the same. It ignores the fact that I've installed Geneva manually, and just keeps trying to download it from the broken URL.

Comment: so I guess you should install all the prerequisites manually and then launch the installation. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2010/06/07/installing-sharepoint-2010-prerequisites-offline.aspx

Comment: I can try doing that, but I doubt it will work, because right now when I run the main installer, it immediately complains about Geneva not being installed, even though I installed it. If it won't work now, with Geneva, I doubt it will work after I install the other dependencies. It'll probably just keep asking for Geneva.

Comment: Thanks for the link you sent. I found out that I can run the PrerequisiteInstaller with a '/IDFX:' switch, which allows me to substitute my own 'Geneva' installer for the default download. So I did that, and the PrerequisiteInstaller ran to the end with no errors. Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem, as  when I run the *main* installer, it still complains that Geneva isn't installed.

Comment: When I check the setup log file, it has the following line: 'Minimum Geneva Framework version 1.0.21023.5 is not installed.'. Yet if I go to Control Panel, Add/Remove Programs, it shows Geneva in the list, with that exact version installed!

Comment: Finally fixed it! Turns out I'd installed the SDK rather than Geneva itself. Finally tracked down the MicrosoftGenevaFramework.x64.msi file on this blog: http://blog.furuknap.net/installing-sharepoint-2010-beta-1. Here's the link to download the correct MSI file: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/6/866E86E1-2264-4C80-836A-92F3F3A3B1AB/release/MicrosoftGenevaFramework.x64.msi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the Prerequisites installer was downloading a 0KB Geneva installation package, because the official Microsoft download URL is down (giving 404 errors).

I found a working link to the installer: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/6/6/866E86E1-2264-4C80-836A-92F3F3A3B1AB/release/MicrosoftGenevaFramework.x64.msi.

So the steps were:

1. Download the MSI file from the link above, to a local folder (e.g. C:\Prerequisites).
2. Run the Prerequisites installer with the '/IDFX' switch (thanks for the blog link, @GillouX!):

   `PrerequisiteInstaller.exe /IDFX:C:\Prerequisites\MicrosoftGenevaFrameworkSDK.x64.msi`

   The Prerequisites installation now proceeds correctly.
3. Then I can run the installer and it works! :)

Comment: Thank you, I see your article to help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To fix just download thew new SPF2010 binary version 14.0.4730.1010